# Regex: Get parts of url with hyphens in reverse order

Tags: regex, url, reverse

I have url like:

```
http://www.example.com/file/golf-background-loop-6863-thumb480x270.jpg
```

Is it possible to capture words sperated by hyphens but in reverse order?

1. thumb480x270.jpg
2. 6863
3. loop
4. background
5. http://www.example.com/file/golf

Or at least match last two:

1. thumb480x270.jpg
2. 6863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally splitting on `-` must be the easiest solution. But just in case you have to use regex

getting the last two words should be easy with a regular expression

```
.*-(\w+)-([\w.:\/]+)$
```

replace with

```
\2-\1
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.prototype.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) functions:

```js
var url = 'http://www.example.com/file/golf-background-loop-6863-thumb480x270.jpg',
    parts = url.split('-').reverse();

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

php.net is your friend

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/file/golf-background-loop-6863-thumb480x270.jpg';

foreach (array_reverse(explode("-", $url)) as $idx => $part) {
    echo $idx + 1, ". ", $part, "\n";
}
```